# Debug application with self-compiled Qt

Tags: qt, debugging, qt5, qt5.4

Since there is no official Qt 5.4.2 binary x64 release for Visual Studio 2010 I have compiled it on my own.

Now when I try to debug my application, it won't link because there are no Qt *d.lib's.

Do I need to compile Qt with debugging information, if I don't want to debug Qt library but only my app?
How to tell qmake/qtcreator to link non-debug Qt with my debug target?

Comment: Did  you try to explicitly define which libraries you want to link against? Something like `LIBS += -Ld:/Qt/5.4.2/lib -lQtCore.lib` or so.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is defined in `prf` files (example for Qt4 - for Qt5 will be similar):

`./mkspecs/features/win32/windows.prf`:

> **9** CONFIG(debug, debug|release): QMAKE_LIBS += $${entryLib}$${QT_LIBINFIX}d

`./mkspecs/features/qt.prf`:

> **112** CONFIG(debug, debug|release):QT_LINKAGE = -l$${QTPLUG}d
>
> **127** CONFIG(debug, debug|release): QT_ITEM = $${QTPLUG}d4.dll

`./mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf`:

> **75** win32:LINKAGE = -l$${LIB_NAME}$${QT_LIBINFIX}d

`./mkspecs/features/uitools.prf`:

> **10** win32: QTUITOOLS_LINKAGE = -lQtUiTools$${QT_LIBINFIX}d

Still, not sure if this will work correctly, that's why I recommend you to build both debug and release version of libraries.